# How can I divide this sentence?

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, oxford-comma

> It also generally implies a particular view of reality of what man, society, and even the physical world like in the nature, behavior and relationship to one another.

Could you divide this sentence with a slash(/) to understand easily? Actucally, I don't know the usage of comma exactly, maybe it makes me more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No slashes, pretty much ever outside of mathematical and scientific applications, and some exceptions like *the Bush/Cheney administration*.
2. Your commas aren't the problem; you're having some ESL issues.
3. Multiple lists in the same sentence are tricky - best not to use them

**It also implies a particular view of reality: namely, what man, society, and the physical world look like in their relationships with each other.**

Comment: Would remove the 's' on 'looks', since you're referring to a list.

Comment: You're right, sir. Edited

Answer (score 1):

You missed the verb *are* (probably that's the reason you couldn't understand this sentence):

> > *It also generally implies a particular view of reality, // of what man, society and even the physical world are like in their nature, behavior and relationship to one another.*

These two sentences can be made form yours (guess these would make it easier for you to understand it):

> > 1- It also generally implies a particular view of reality
> >
> > 2- It also generally implies a particular view of what man, society and even the physical world are like in their nature, behavior and relationship to one another.

By the way, [hemingwayapp.com](http://www.hemingwayapp.com/) or [dissertationwriter.org](http://dissertationwriter.org) can be of help in such questions.

Best

Comment: Thanks! However, I thought verb 'are' is related to man, society, and even physical world, not of reality and of what man ~ (blah). Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: yes, you are right. *are* is related to 'what man, society, and even physical world' and 'what' there is related to 'man', 'society' and 'physical world' >> ..view of what man is like..;..view of what society is like..;.. view of what the physical world is like..;